# Javascript - call websevice on different subdoman?

Tags: javascript, web-services

After some research, It is my understanding that you can not call a web service in javascript that is on an external domain.
What about a sub domain?
My website is on http://example.com and i have some web services on http://services.example.com.

Is this case, would I be able to call them?

Thank you.

Comment: well if the web service accepts json data..you can use javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you can't call webservices in other domains (different domain name or port).

However if you control the webservice it't possible to wrap it using JSONP. Technically,
with every call a script is embedded in your page, wchich calls a function already defined within your page passing it the data returned from the webservice call.

Most libraries support this kind of cross domain communication including jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you need to do some work.
Look at the CORS specifications, here are some links to go through:

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control

Specially look for Access-Control-Allow-Origin. That is the way you want to go for.

Answer (score 0):

What I find useful in these situations (where I have control over both servers), is to post to a file on the same domain which then posts to the other domain.